# Facebook logout() not running? Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

I faced problem, when the user click on the log out button. It trigger the php script and logout. But still after logout it still auto log in. Is my logout functions not running? If in the same page, it is working but when I tried the logout button at other page. It won't work.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
    require_once "config.php";
    unset($_SESSION['access_token']);

    if($_SESSION['account_type'] == "google"){
                //GOOGle logout
    }
    else if($_SESSION['account_type'] == "facebook"){
        ?>
        <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            // init the FB JS SDK
            FB.init({
                appId: '877717879076949', 
                channelUrl: 'elisa.com.my',
                status: true,
                xfbml: true
            });
        };

        function fb_logout() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    window.location = 'https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?access_token=' + response.authResponse.accessToken + '&next=elisa.com.my/index.php';
                }
            });
        }

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/zh_TW/all.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>

        <?php

    }

    session_destroy();

    echo "<script>window.location.href = 'index.php';</script>";
    exit();
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

My button is at another page which is this code:

```
<a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>
```

Comment: Do your other pages embed the JS SDK in the same way? If so, then this is simply the _auto-login_ functionality at work ... This logout only logs the user out of your app, not Facebook, if they were logged in to Facebook before already. So if you set the JS SDK up to automatically recognize users that are logged in to Facebook and have connected to your app before, then this is simply what happens ... (Logout of your app only logs the user out of Facebook as well, if they specifically logged into Facebook during the process of logging in to your app in the first place.)